# How can I use MapActivity in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building an android application and using mapActivity.

But, the problem is that there is no displaying of map when I run my application.

Here is my Activity code:

```
public class MainActivitytut extends FragmentActivity{

GoogleMap map;
private static MapController mMapController;
private static final LatLng GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE = 
        new LatLng(37.828891,-122.485884);
private static final LatLng APPLE = 
        new LatLng(37.3325004578, -122.03099823);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maintut);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (map == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not available", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/locinfo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The question is updated as per latest Google Map needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the updated code for your question:

```
package com.amal.googlemap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivitytut extends FragmentActivity{

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    LatLng latLng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maintut);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

     // Getting a reference to the map
            googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

            // Setting a click event handler for the map
            googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {               

                    // Getting the Latitude and Longitude of the touched location
                    latLng = arg0;
                    String lat = latLng.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat,
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Clears the previously touched position
                    googleMap.clear();

                    // Animating to the touched position                                
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));             

                    // Creating a marker
                    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                    // Setting the position for the marker
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);                     

                    // Placing a marker on the touched position
                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    // Adding Marker on the touched location with address
                    new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng);             

                }
            });


//        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
//        if (map == null) {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not available", 
//                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            
//        }


   }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
        // present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }
//    @Override
//    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// 
//        switch (item.getItemId()) {
// 
//        case R.id.menu_sethybrid:
//            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
//            break;
// 
//        case R.id.menu_showtraffic:
//            map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
//            break;
// 
//        case R.id.menu_zoomin:
//            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
//            break;
// 
//        case R.id.menu_zoomout:
//            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
//            break;
// 
//        case R.id.menu_gotolocation:
//            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
//                .target(GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE) // Sets the center of the map to
//                                            // Golden Gate Bridge
//                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
//                .bearing(90) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
//                .tilt(30)    // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
//                .build();    // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
//            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
//                cameraPosition));
//            break;
// 
//        case R.id.menu_addmarker:
//            // ---using the default marker---
//            /*
//            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
//                .position(GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE)
//                .title("Golden Gate Bridge") .snippet("San Francisco")
//                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
//                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
//            */
// 
//            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
//                .position(GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE)
//                .title("Golden Gate Bridge")
//                .snippet("San Francisco")
//                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
//                .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
//            break;
// 
//        case R.id.menu_getcurrentlocation:
//            // ---get your current location and display a blue dot---
//            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
// 
//            break;
// 
//        case R.id.menu_showcurrentlocation:
//            Location myLocation = map.getMyLocation();
//            LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),
//                    myLocation.getLongitude());
// 
//            CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
//                    .target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
//            map.animateCamera(
//                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));
//            break;
//            
//        case R.id.menu_lineconnecttwopoints:
//            //---add a marker at Apple---
//            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
//                    .position(APPLE)
//                    .title("Apple")
//                    .snippet("Cupertino")
//                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
//                              BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
// 
//            //---draw a line connecting Apple and Golden Gate Bridge---
//            map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
//                .add(GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE, APPLE).width(5).color(Color.RED));
//            break;
//        }
//        return true;
//    }


    private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String>{
        Context mContext;

        public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context){
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }

        // Finding address using reverse geocoding
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
            double latitude = params[0].latitude;
            double longitude = params[0].longitude;

            List<Address> addresses = null;
            String addressText="";

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 ){
                Address address = addresses.get(0);

                addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        address.getLocality(),                      
                        address.getCountryName());              
            }

            return addressText;
        }       

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {
            // Setting the title for the marker. 
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(addressText);

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Thanks Android Man I used this but there is no displaying lat and long.

Comment: @Sonam: Have you cleaned the project?? If not please clean it... Please check my code I have toasted the latlng.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could explain the changes you made and elaborate on what the original problem was, why your changes fixed them, and why you chose to do it they way you did.

Answer (score -1):

You have to obtain a signature key for your app and the Google API.

Follow the instructions to get your Maps working on [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).

Here is a tutorial where the signing process is explained in [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html).

You should register a debug and a production key for the develop and release version of your app.